# Gradle project refresh failed: Cause: repository not found:

Tags: javascript, java, spring, intellij-idea, gradle

I am facing this below issue
Gradle 'CUST' project refresh failed:
         Cause: repository not found: C:\ROLBWorkspace\CUST
         Gradle settings

My project path is 
C:\ROLBWorkspace\CUST

My gradle path
C:\Progs\gradle-1.10-bin\gradle-1.10